# What is required to claim Canadian citizenship?

Tags: canada, citizenship, canadian-citizens

My father is a Canadian citizen by birth (born in Canada), my mother and I are both American citizens. We all live in the United States (my father as a green-card permanent resident -- he has been an ex-pat my whole life). I am 26 years old.

Am I eligible to claim Canadian citizenship?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably are a Canadian citizen, in which case, yes.

The [page on citizenship rules](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/canadian-citizenship/become-canadian-citizen/eligibility/already-citizen.html) suggests that you have been a Canadian citizen from birth because your father is a Canadian citizen born in Canada.

Some countries will adjudicate your claim to citizenship as part of an initial passport application, but Canada seems to want you to [apply for a certificate of citizenship first](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/canadian-passports/new-adult-passport/citizenship-proof.html), which [costs $75 and takes about five months](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/canadian-citizenship/proof-citizenship/about.html) (Canadian dollars).